# Excel - Monthly Average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi

I'm creating a pivot table that looks at per person analysis vs group average. Trying to create a pivot table, to do a comparison analysis (each person vs the group average) on a month over month analysis. As you can see i have a 4th column titled average, as im not sure how to get the average for the group though per month seeing how the data is spread out.

my test data;
http://www.mediafire.com/file/3yyriggqduw6ldw/file

Comment: Post data instead of image so that we can copy and paste to excel for analysis.

Comment: Is there any Group column? or you just wants compare a person's average vs all person's average?

Comment: What do you expect your results to look like (given the data you show)?  What have you done so far to solve this problem?

Comment: @Harun24HR I posted a link to mediaFire to download the dataset.

Comment: @mkRabbani There is no group column. Just need to compare a persons vs all person average

Comment: So you need number of rows as number of employee, right? unfortunately your sample image is not opening here. Anyway, best practice is to avoid image for showing sample data. Can you add your data as table here?

Comment: With Power Query it's pretty simple (using grouping) to get monthly all-person averages (and Standard Deviations, and other statistical information).  But without knowing more about what you want for output, or where you have run into trouble, it's hard to provide more advice..

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sumif/countif on the range for only the year & month

(if would be year=row year and month=row month)

Answer (score 0):

You basically need 2 measure as below-

1.

```
person_wise_average = AVERAGE(your_table_name[sale])
```

2. 

```
overall_average = 
AVERAGEX(
    ALL(your_table_name),
    your_table_name[sale]
)
```

Now just add three column to your table visual - "person name", "person_wise_average" and "overall_average". You should now have all your values in the presentation.